# Add more views to viewPager, Android

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

Working in android I have followed an online tutorial to create a view pager which I want to programmatically add text to. I have successfully created the bulk of it adding 4 views, however when I scroll between the views I am always getting the same view. My code is as follows. Is there a way that the initial view will simply say Page1 then when scrolled it will say Page2 so and so forth.

**Edit**

Just to clarify, I have rather simplified what I want to do here, the end goal is for each "view" to be different. For example Page 1 contains a textview, page 2 contains an image view, page 3 contains some larger text.

```
Page 1 = "This is page 1"
Page 2 = An image of a sheep
Page 3 = Big red text saying "BANG!"
```

**XML**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/black">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/myImage"
            android:id="@+id/imageView13" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Testing extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_testing);

        ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        vp.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(this));
    }
}

class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context ctx;

    public MyPagerAdapter(Context context) {
        ctx = context;
    }

    // Set number of slides
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

        TextView tv =  new TextView(ctx);
        tv.setTextSize(50);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        tv.setText("PAGE1");
        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(tv);
        return tv;
    }

    // Destroy
    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view) {
        ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((View) view);
    }

    // View from object
    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    // Parceable
    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }

    // Restore state
    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable arg0, ClassLoader arg1) {
    }

    //Start Update
    @Override
    public void startUpdate(View arg0) {
    }

    // Finish update
    @Override
    public void finishUpdate(View arg0) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

position change when you scroll your page...

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

if(position==0){
    TextView tv =  new TextView(ctx);
    tv.setTextSize(50);
    tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    tv.setText("PAGE "+position);
    collection.addView(tv);
    return tv;
}else if(position==1){
   ImageView iv = new ImageView(ctx);
   iv.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
   collection.addView(iv);
   return iv;
}else if(position==2){
   TextView tv =  new TextView(ctx);
    tv.setTextSize(50);
    tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    tv.setText("BANG");
    collection.addView(tv);
    return tv;
}else if(position==3){
   ImageView iv = new ImageView(ctx);
   iv.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
   collection.addView(tv);
    return iv;
}
```

Comment: Apologies I seem to have simplified my problem, I have edited the question.